# Horizontal Bar extending outer container

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I would search for, but I believe it's just as simple as changing the type of position: to be used in CSS.

I have a Container DIV (width: 960px), and I want an orange "bar" in it somewhere, but it will be wider than its container, it will be 100%. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning to achieve this effect.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="orange-bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#orange-bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/2/

Comment: @Mayankswami. What is still wider?

Comment: EvilCokeMachine wants the bar to be wider than the container div: "...but it will be wider than its container."

Comment: @JSW189 - Regarding this answer, it works brilliantly, but when I place code beneath this orange bar, it doesn't display beneath the orange bar in the webpage, it displays up above the orange bar on the webpage. How can I make it go beneath it? I tried setting position: absolute to relative, but that gets rid of the 100%-width effect.

Comment: I have updated your original code to reproduce the current problem I am experiencing: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/5/

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine. The orange bar is positioned with `margin-top: 100px`. If you want the text to go below the bar, use `p { padding-top: 200px }` (the margin + the height of the orange bar). JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/11/

Comment: Ah, thank you heaps JSW.. I had a feeling it would be done that way, but I guess I just thought it would be a little more complicated than that.