# Code beneath orange bar appears above orange bar in webpage

Tags: html, css

I have an orange bar on my webpage which is the host of a slideshow control.
The orange container div is set to extend the outer width of the main page div, as shown below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/2

However, when I try to add more content to my webpage, any further content appears directly above the orange bar, instead of beneath it. The only way I can get more content to appear beneath the orange bar, is to change the orange bar's position to relative (from absolute) - which defeats the whole purpose of the orange bar - and the absolute setting.

For implementation code that I am using, see my first question:
[Horizontal Bar extending outer container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601946/horizontal-bar-extending-outer-container)

---

Below is a visual of how I would like this to look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/5

But this is how it's actually appearing (very bad):

[image]

*How can I have my content appear beneath the orange bar?*

---

**Fiddle *without* content after bar: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/2)

Fiddle *with* content after bar: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/5)**

Comment: @AhmadAlfy JSFiddle _without_ content after bar: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/2/ and JSFiddle _with_ content after bar: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top` to the `paragraph`.

```css
p {
   padding-top: 200px;    
}
```

**Working fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/8/)**.

Comment: No offense, but isn't this just a quick fix? I mean, for every other separate div, or span, or p or whatever, I'll have to add padding-top: 200px; to it. Isn't there a more proper workaround?

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine What's wrong with the `padding`? It's there with a reason: to position your elements as you like.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just thought it was a little strange is all. You know... Having to pad down by 200px and all..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8uL/9/)

The way you code it interfers with the flow of the page ... An absolutely positioned element will always lie above any other element moving within the flow